# .getText().toString() gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps

Here is my code for adding markers in google maps android api v2.
My problem is I cant get the String value from my EditText snippet. The code .getText().toString() cant get the string value and only sends null. 
Please help me.

```
    googlemap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(final LatLng latlng) {
            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View v = li.inflate(R.layout.alertlayout, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setView(v);
            builder.setCancelable(false);

            builder.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    EditText title = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.ettitle);
                    EditText snippet = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etsnippet);
                    String s = title.getText().toString();
                    String ss = snippet.getText().toString();
                    googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .title(s)
                            .snippet(ss)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                            .position(latlng)
                            );
                }
            });

            //Create Negative button
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code in

onMapLongClick()

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlayout, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null pointer because you don't have implemented getter and setter for that edit text values you need to follow this..

1. Inflate your layout properly like..

   ```
   LayoutInflater mInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   ```

   convertView =mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlayout,null);

2.Crate ViewHolder class containing getter and setter for that edit text.

1. `convertView.setTag(holder);`
2. create holder object like `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();`
   now you can get `holder.get....();`